# Native promises vs. Bluebird promises

Tags: node.js, bluebird, es6-promise

Is there a way in Node.js to check to determine if `global.Promise` is the native promise implementation? As opposed to Bluebird promises, etc?

Comment: You could do the opposite by duck typing on the API. Say `.promisifyAll` for bluebird or `.fapply` for Q but that doesn't help detecting native. I'm not sure that replacing global.Promise is a good idea in the first place.

Comment: @Matt I am not replacing global.Promise, the users of my library might do it though, I have no control over that, but need to detect it. I agree that replacing global.Promise is probably a bad move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a feature test and test to see if any of the Bluebird extended features are present:

```
function testBluebird() {
   // test to see if a representative sample of Bluebird-specific features are present
   return Promise && Promise.join && Promise.try && Promise.method && Promise.map;
}
```

Like with many things in Javascript, you should probably just test to see if the features you want to use are present rather than trying to determine if a specific library is loaded.

Comment: thanks, I am most interested in determining if a promise is native, not if a promise is Bluebird, but this should work for Bluebird

Comment: @AlexanderMills - What problem are you really trying to solve?  Why do you want to know if it's native?  There are certainly other non-native Promise implementations besides Bluebird so this returning `false` won't guarantee that promises are native.

Comment: I need to patch the native Promise implementation, but I don't want to patch Promise if it's not native.

Comment: @AlexanderMills - Patch it for what?  If you tell us the real problem, we can offer you more direct advice on your actual problem.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know if global.Promise is the native Promise implementation or some other implementation. I need to know if it's the native Promise. I am monkey-patching then(), see: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/555

Comment: There are other reasons why you'd want to know if global.Promise is native or Bluebird - mostly for debugging to see if the right code is loaded, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderMills - So, the real issue is that you're trying to decide if you can/should monkey patch the current promise implememtation for domains?

Comment: I know that I can monkey patch global.Promise, but I only want to monkey patch it if it's the native implementation :) However, if you have any feedback as to whether the patch that I mentioned in the link is any good, feedback is more than welcome.

Comment: @AlexanderMills - Sorry, but I don't understand domains well enough to comment on that.  You might want to ask a separate question about that particular topic.

Comment: yeah I asked node core about both - patching ES6 native promises to work with domains and also how to id Promise as native, working on answers here to all of the above

Comment: to learn about domains, you can play with the example I showed, comment out the monkey patch and you will see the difference, just save it to a file and run the file with node

Comment: const then = Promise.prototype.then;Promise.prototype.then = function (fn1, fn2) { if (process.domain) {  fn1 = fn1 && process.domain.bind(fn1);
    fn2 = fn2 && process.domain.bind(fn2);}return then.call(this, fn1, fn2);
};process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
    console.log(' This is uncaught => ', err);
});const domain = require('domain');const d = domain.create();d.on('error', function(err){
  console.error(' => Domain caught => ',err);
});d.run(function(){Promise.resolve().then(function(){
     process.nextTick(function(){
       throw new Error('rah');
     });});});

Comment: copy the above to a file